# when I pass the URL in postman then debugger not come to the controller give an error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postman

I m fetching data which id=100 and data is display successfully see the select command

I want to get the data from the database but issue is when I enter this url then debugger not come to the contoller

**Postman**

GET        http://localhost:000/HomeController/List?getID=100          //problem is here when click the send button debugger not come to the controller and give the error in postman

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:0000/Home/List?getID=100'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'Home'."}

HomeController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public JObject List(int getID)
{
    return Methods.methodclass.methodname(getID);
}
```

sp run the successfully when pass the select command

```
select * from Status WHERE ID = 100;  //id is 100
```

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[herespname] 
  @ID int
AS
BEGIN
    select * from status WHERE ID = @ID; 
END
```

**main issue is my URL is not work in postman that is the main issue**

please help

which place I m doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried this `http://localhost:000/HomeController/List?getID=100` or this `http://localhost:0000/Home/List?getID=100`? the last should work.

Comment: Check if there is any filter overr controller.

Comment: @Always_a_learner not apply any filter on the controller